# How to generate AWS Guardduty IAM findings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-guardduty

Use Case: Build an alert based on GuardDuty IAM finding.
I want "real" events and not sample findings for federated user with actual PrincipalIDs.

Hot to generate IAM security events? Is there a script/ console action I can try ?

I added my IP address in the threat list and performed few operations but still nothing in the GuardDuty finding.